# Nodejs sqs queue processor

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I am trying to write a nodejs sqs queue processor.

```
"use strict";
var appConf = require('./config/appConf');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config/aws_config.json');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function readMessage() {
  sqs.receiveMessage({
    "QueueUrl": appConf.sqs_distribution_url,
    "MaxNumberOfMessages": 1,
    "VisibilityTimeout": 30,
    "WaitTimeSeconds": 20
  }, function (err, data) {
    var sqs_message_body;
    if (data.Messages) {
      if (typeof data.Messages[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof data.Messages[0].Body !== 'undefined') {
        //sqs msg body
        sqs_message_body = JSON.parse(data.Messages[0].Body);
        //make call to nodejs handler in codeigniter
        exec('php '+ appConf.CI_FC_PATH +'/index.php nodejs_handler make_contentq_call "'+ sqs_message_body.contentq_cat_id+'" "'+sqs_message_body.cnhq_cat_id+'" "'+sqs_message_body.network_id+'"',
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            }
            console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
            if(stdout == 'Success'){
              //delete message from queue
              sqs.deleteMessage({
                "QueueUrl" : appConf.sqs_distribution_url,
                "ReceiptHandle" :data.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle
              });
            }
          });
      }
    }
  });
}
readMessage();
```

The above code works fine for single message in queue. How should I write this script so that it keeps polling for messages in queue untill all messages are processed? Should i use set timeout?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all you should definetely use **long polling** technique provided by Amazon, and as I understand you are already using it because you have `"WaitTimeSeconds": 20` argument in `sqs.receiveMessage` call. I hope that you didn't forget to configure it in the [AWS Web interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html).

About polling for messages - you may use different techniques including timers, but I think the most simple will be just call your `readMessage()` function at the end of `receiveMessage`'s (or even `exec`'s) callback function. So processing of (or waiting for) the  next message in queue will start immediately after the end of processing of previous message in queue.

**UPDATE:**

As for me in your new version of code there are to many `readMessage()` calls. I think it is better to minimize it to keep code more clear and easy to maintain. But if you leave, for example, the only one call at the end of your main `receiveMessage` callback you will recieve a lot of PHP worker scripts running in parallel - and maybe it is not so bad from the point of view of performance - but you will have to add some complicated script to control the amount of parallel workers. I think you can cut some calls in `exec` callback, try to join `if`s and join calls in main callback.

```
"use strict";
var appConf = require('./config/appConf');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config/aws_config.json');
var delay = 20 * 1000;
var sqs = new AWS.SQS();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function readMessage() {
  sqs.receiveMessage({
    "QueueUrl": appConf.sqs_distribution_url,
    "MaxNumberOfMessages": 1,
    "VisibilityTimeout": 30,
    "WaitTimeSeconds": 20
  }, function (err, data) {
    var sqs_message_body;
    if (data.Messages) 
      && (typeof data.Messages[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof data.Messages[0].Body !== 'undefined')) {
        //sqs msg body
        sqs_message_body = JSON.parse(data.Messages[0].Body);
        //make call to nodejs handler in codeigniter
        exec('php '+ appConf.CI_FC_PATH +'/index.php nodejs_handler make_contentq_call "'+ sqs_message_body.contentq_cat_id+'" "'+sqs_message_body.cnhq_cat_id+'" "'+sqs_message_body.network_id+'"',
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
              // error handling 
            }
            if(stdout == 'Success'){
              //delete message from queue
              sqs.deleteMessage({
                "QueueUrl" : appConf.sqs_distribution_url,
                "ReceiptHandle" :data.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle
              }, function(err, data){                
              });
            }
            readMessage();                
          });
      }          
    }        
    readMessage();        
  });
}
readMessage();
```

About memory leaks: I think that you should not worry because the next call of `readMessage()` happens in callback function - so not recursively, and recursively called function returns value to parent function just after calling `receiveMessage()` function.

Comment: Hello, please review my this gist. https://gist.github.com/yalamber/374add88e887e688d818

Comment: Also Should i worry about any memory leak while running this script?

Comment: Old post, but did you encounter any problems with memory leak, because I am using almost same idea with Bluebird promises. And on each poll I can see that the heap's total is growing about 200kb.

Comment: I think this approach still leaks memory.

Comment: @napalm please add more details, it will be helpful

Comment: I'll update your answer about the memory leak. It involves solution from http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Comment: @RistoNovik over a year later and I am seeing the same thing, with Bluebird promises heap is growing really quickly. Did you come up with a solution that worked well?

Comment: Just asking are you using latest Node version and bluebird package? Besides this, remember the Node GC is lazy by default v8 options allow 1.5GB heap size.

Comment: The leak might be because this is using recursion. Node/Js has no tail call optimization, so it keeps all the stack in memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using node, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-worker module. It will do the job for you.

```
var SQSWorker = require('sqs-worker')

var options =
 { url: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/001123456789/my-queue'
}

var queue = new SQSWorker(options, worker)

function worker(notifi, done) {
  var message;
  try {
    message = JSON.parse(notifi.Data)
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }

   // Do something with `message` 

   var success = true

   // Call `done` when you are done processing a message. 
   // If everything went successfully and you don't want to see it any more, 
   // set the second parameter to `true`. 
   done(null, success)
}
```

Comment: why the down-vote?  https://github.com/BBC/sqs-consumer is an alternative as well

Comment: `sqs-worker` is version 0.0.2, last published in 2014. But `sqs-consumer` seems a bit more active, and has a lot more downloads. Probably you should make that the answer instead :-)