# node.js using SQS need functional example

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-sqs

```
var params = {
    QueueUrl: sqsEndPoint + compInfoQueName,
    AttributeNames: [All],
    MaxNumberOfMessages: '5',
    MessageAttributeNames: [],
    ReceiveRequestAttemptId: "",
    VisibilityTimeout: '15',
    WaitTimeSeconds: '10'
};

sqs.receiveMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else return data;
});
```

Got this from AWS website

I have all the params set and can get a response on an html page using:

https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT/QUEUENAME";

But I am wanting to integrate this into a node.js project

I am new to javascript, in java I would just import the AWS object and call a method in a function ie.

function...
{json response = sqs.receive... }

How do I use the code at the top in JS?

How do I set a string object to a result from receive with the code example?

I just want to set a field in an html page to the received sqs message

textarea.value = myMessageFromAWS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs sqs queue processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716401/nodejs-sqs-queue-processor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you come from Java the callbacks are not very intuitive.

I'd recommend you to use the async/await approach so the code looks more linear, like this:

```js
async function main () {
  var params = {
    QueueUrl: sqsEndPoint + compInfoQueName,
    AttributeNames: [All],
    MaxNumberOfMessages: '5',
    MessageAttributeNames: [],
    ReceiveRequestAttemptId: "",
    VisibilityTimeout: '15',
    WaitTimeSeconds: '10'
  };

  try {
    // this will be your data received from sqs
    const data = await sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise()
    // prints to stdout
    console.log(data)

  } catch(err) {
    // prints to stderr
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  };
}

// Because this is not Java you have to call this function explicitly
main()
```

Comment: what if i want to continuously check for messages, is it a right way to call the main function a timout function with 1 s interval ?